# Delete all data from MySQL table with button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am currently trying to implement a 'Delete' button that clears a MySQL table of all its data. I am finding it much more difficult than the submit button was.

Researched examples all show how to do it by a row, but I just have a single 'Delete' button. I believe I am currently way off, as I was trying to come up with a solution based on the submit Ajax function.

Currently:

**HTML**

```
<button class="myButton" id="delete" type="delete">DELETE</button>
```

**JavaScript** (This is where my hangup is I think)

```
function deleteMessage() {

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'info_message.php',
        async: false,
        //data: ,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "success") {
                successPopup("Successfully deleted message");
            }
            else {
                alert("Unable to delete message. " + response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP** (or here???)

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteMessage'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Deletes all records in Announcement table
    $query = "DELETE from Announcement";
    if ($dbc->query($query) === FALSE) {
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $dbc->error;
    }
    else {
        echo "success";
    }

    exit();
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any data to the PHP file in your ajax call... `//data: ,`

Comment: @Nick ok, I guess that leaves me to this question then. How or what data would I pass to make it then delete all data from the sql table?

Comment: Does your query work or not? @flyboy Did you see the answer given below also?

Comment: btw if its a large table, and you don't care about other concurrent transactions, 'TRUNCATE TABLE Announcement' will be quicker. It may need an additional GRANT to the user to run this (if the original database user was restricted according to best practices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking for post data which you're not passing with your ajax call. Specifically you need to add deleteMessage and message which is the 2 post variables you are trying to read in your php script. Something like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'info_message.php',
        async: false,
        data: { deleteMessage: true, message:"insert what message you want to pass" } ,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "success") {
                successPopup("Successfully deleted message");
            }
            else {
                alert("Unable to delete message. " + response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```